# Couchdb 'init terminating in do_boot' error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, ubuntu-14.04

I installed couchdb in Ubuntu 14.04 using `apt-get`.

When i try to run it, i get the following error:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{bad_return,{{couch_app,start,[normal,["/etc/couchdb/default.ini","/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,{error,enoent}}},[{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,[{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,56}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,269}]}]}}}}}},[{couch,start,0,[{file,"couch.erl"},{line,18}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

My environment is Erlang: R16B03 in ubuntu 14.04. I use nginx (with ssl enabled). Should I do anything specific with my nginx configuration file?

When i do `couchdb -b`, I get:

```
Apache CouchDB needs write permission on the PID file: /var/run/couchdb/couchdb.pid
```

And, when I do `sudo chown -R couchdb /var/run/couchdb`, I get the following:

```
chown: cannot access ‘/var/run/couchdb’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can manually create couchdb directory under /var/run and give it couchdb:couchdb ownership.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to change the owner of the couchdb directory under /var/run however it doesn't exist yet.

Create the directory with:

```
sudo mkdir /var/run/couchdb
```

you can then run your change owner command

```
sudo chown -R couchdb /var/run/couchdb
```

Comment: I have to do this every time restart the machine. Any permanent fix for this issue?